# How can I prevent Jackson from serializing a polymorphic type's annotation property?

Tags: java, json, jackson

I have polymorphic types and deserializing from JSON to POJO works. I followed the documentation [here](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-docs/wiki/JacksonPolymorphicDeserialization), in fact. When serializing POJOs into JSON I'm getting an unwanted attribute, specifically the logical type name.

```
import static org.codehaus.jackson.annotate.JsonTypeInfo.*;

@JsonTypeInfo(use=Id.NAME, include=As.PROPERTY, property="type")
@JsonSubTypes({
    @JsonSubTypes.Type(value=Dog.class, name="dog"),
    @JsonSubTypes.Type(value=Cat.class, name="cat")
})    
public class Animal { ... }

public class Dog extends Animal { ... }
public class Cat extends Animal { ... }
```

When Jackson serializes into JSON it provides the type information which I don't want to expose.

```
{"type":"dog", ... }
{"type":"cat", ... }
```

Can I prevent this somehow? I only want to ignore `type` when deserializing.

Comment: You said, "I only want to ignore type when deserializing."  Did you instead mean, "I only want to ignore type when serializing."?

Comment: I'm impressed you managed to figure out this much from the documentation.  There isn't a single usage example of `@JsonSubTypes` on that wiki page.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A simple solution would be to just move the `@JsonTypeInfo` and `@JsonSubTypes` configs to a `MixIn`, and then only register the `MixIn` for deserialization.

`mapper.getDeserializationConfig().addMixInAnnotations(MyClass.class, MyMixIn.class)`

Comment: Can you please share solution code which has solved your problem.

Comment: http://programmerbruce.blogspot.com/2011/05/deserialize-json-with-jackson-into.html

Answer (score 9):

This took me a long time to solve so I thought I'd share.

```
@JsonTypeInfo(use = JsonTypeInfo.Id.NAME, include = JsonTypeInfo.As.EXISTING_PROPERTY,
visible = false, property = "type")
```

`visible=false` ensures that if the property `type` exists on the class, it will not be populated with the value of `type` during deserialization.

`include = JsonTypeInfo.As.EXISTING_PROPERTY` dictates that if the property `type` exists, use that value during serialization otherwise do nothing.

So putting it all together:

```java
import static org.codehaus.jackson.annotate.JsonTypeInfo.*;

@JsonTypeInfo(use = Id.NAME, include = As.EXISTING_PROPERTY, visible = false, property = "type")
@JsonSubTypes({
    @JsonSubTypes.Type(value=Dog.class, name="dog"),
    @JsonSubTypes.Type(value=Cat.class, name="cat")
})    
public class Animal { ... }

public class Dog extends Animal { ... }
public class Cat extends Animal { ... }
```

Comment: This does not answer the question asked.

Comment: @Siddhu I have edited my response to better address the question asked. Thanks for the feedback. Hope it helps.