# FasterXML Jackson: The JSON @ symbol?

Tags: java, json, jackson

i have the following JSON:

```
"segmentid": {
    "mot": {
        "@displaytype": "B",
        "@type": "BLT",
        "#text": "Buss"
    },...
```

The following questions:

- What is the `@` notation for?
- If it is used for a specific reason, how can I use it in Jackson?

Comment: What makes you think it's Jackson specific and not just the name of a JSON key?

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis Sorry if I was unclear but I know that it is not Jackson specific, it is JSON specific. I was asking if it is possible to be used by Jackson somehow.

Comment: It definitely isn't JSON specific because the [JSON specification](http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7159) gives no special meaning to the character `@` or `#`. I've seen it used in Jackson in its inheritance hierarchy handling, but there's no indication that that is what you have here (except that it is called _type_).

Comment: See [here](http://programmerbruce.blogspot.com/2011/05/deserialize-json-with-jackson-into.html) for example. Or [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21485923/java-jackson-polymorphic-json-deserialization-of-an-object-with-an-interface-pr) (older version).

Comment: [Here's](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23029707/jackson-polymorphic-deserialization) another one.

Comment: "@" is a Unicode character.  An JSON string is a sequence of such characters.  They mean whatever they mean to the programmer.

Answer (score 4):

In this case it seems to be just a normal JSON propety.

You can grab it by using the `@JsonProperty` annotation in your class:

```
public YourJacksonClass {
     @JsonProperty("@displayType")
     private String displayType;

     @JsonProperty("@type")
     private String type;

     @JsonProperty("#text")
     private String text;
}
```

Or, if you are using the `readTree` method which returns a `JsonNode`, just access it normally:

```
JsonNode node = mapper.readTree(...);
String type = node.get("segmentid").get("mot").get("@type");
```

It is also common to use '@'-prefixed properties when it is necessary to serialize type info together with the object.

```
@JsonTypeInfo(use=JsonTypeInfo.Id.CLASS, include=JsonTypeInfo.As.PROPERTY, property="@type")
```

The read type, `"BLT"` in your case, can then be transformed into an actual type when using a `TypeIdResolver` in your `ObjectMapper`.