# Why is Jackson Adding @ to Some JSON Attributes and How To Prevent It?

Tags: java, json, jackson, jax-rs

I am using Jackson in Java to return a JSON response from a REST endpoint. This is an example response that is generated:

```
{"StatusCode":{"@statusCode":"OK"},"SomeElements":null}
```

Questions:

1. Why is Jackson adding the @ in?
2. How can I stop it from adding it?

**Note: This question is different from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28999427/fasterxml-jackson-the-json-symbol) in the sense that I want to know WHY Jackson is adding it and also how to prevent it from doing so as it can cause issues in the systems it is passing the response to.**

**EDIT:**

Here's the sanitized code:

```
public enum StatusCodeType {
    OK, WARNING, ERROR
}

@XmlType(name = "StatusResponse", namespace = "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema/<obfuscated>", propOrder = {"statusCode", "message"})
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class StatusResponse {
    @XmlAttribute(name = "statusCode", required = true)
    private StatusCodeType statusCode;
    @XmlAttribute(name = "message")
    private String message;

    public StatusResponse(final StatusCodeType statusCode, final String message) {
        this.statusCode = statusCode;
        this.message = message;
    }

    public StatusResponse(final StatusCodeType statusCode) {
        this.statusCode = statusCode;
    }

    public StatusResponse() {
    }

    public StatusCodeType getStatusCode() {
        return statusCode;
    }

    public void setStatusCode(StatusCodeType statusCode) {
        this.statusCode = statusCode;
    }

    public void setMessage(String message) {
        this.message = message;
    }
}

@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public abstract class SomeResponse {

    @XmlElement(name = "StatusCode", required = true)
    private StatusResponse statusResponse;

    public StatusResponse getStatusResponse() {
        return statusResponse;
    }

    public void setStatusResponse(StatusResponse statusResponse) {
        this.statusResponse = statusResponse;
    }
}

@XmlRootElement(name = "XmlResponse", namespace = "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema/<obfuscated>")
public class XmlResponse extends SomeResponse {

    @XmlElement(name = "SomeElement")
    @XmlElementWrapper(name = "SomeElements", required = true)
    private List<SomeElement> someElements;

    public List<SomeElement> getSomeElements() {
        return someElements;
    }

    public void setSomeElements(List<SomeElement> someElements) {
        this.someElements = someElements;
    }
}

@Path("/getAll")
@GET
@Produces({MediaType.APPLICATION_XML, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON})
public Response getAll(@QueryParam("firstParam") String firstParam, @QueryParam("secondParam") String secondParam) {
    ...

    final XmlResponse resp = processToXmlResponse(someObject);
    return Response.ok().entity(resp).build();
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You probably have [jettison](https://github.com/codehaus/jettison) on your classpath and it's provider is used for serialization instead of jackson.

By default Jettison will prefix properties mapped to attributes with '@'.

See https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-core/issues/114.