# How to serialize/desrialize JSON with "$type" attribute in JAVA

Tags: java, json

I have to make websocket server to work with JSON objects. The interesting part is that incoming and outgoing JSON has an attribute "$type" (yes, with the $ sign). Example:

```
{
  "$type": "dog",
  "name": "Rex",
  "color": "brown"
}
```

Is there any library that support this "$type" attribute? And if there isn't, what would be the correct way to read and add that "$type" attribute

Comment: Possible dupe of https://stackoverflow.com/a/28999460/1315130

In your pojo can you not add @JsonProperty("$type") to the 'type' field?

Comment: It depends on what the aim is.  Jackson will deserialize this to a `Map` out of the box.  If you want to map this onto a POJO, you'll need to do a little more work, though.