# What does an at sign (@) mean in a serialized array?

Tags: javascript, php, http

In my PHP endpoint, I have logged a serialized array of POST values, but am unable to access any items within the array.  I know the array isn't empty, because I can see the values when I serialize it.  Here is the serialized array:

```
a:1:@s:13:"{"answer":42";s:0:"";}
```

What does the at sign (@) mean?

**Additional information:**

If I call end() or reset() on the unserialized array, both return an empty string.

In the javascript application where I make the POST request, I stringify an object and then use that string as the body of the post:

```
let b = {answer: 42}
...
body: JSON.stringify(b)
```

I use fetch to make the POST.  The content-type header for my POST is 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded', though I'm open to using something else if appropriate.  I tried 'text/html; charset=utf-8' as well, but in that case the array is empty.

Comment: Why would you serialize a JSON string that you mad into an array?

Comment: You have a PHP serialized array with a string of 13 characters containing a JSON-string.

Comment: `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`,.. you might want `application/json`

Comment: @AbraCadaver -- I serialized the array for debugging purposes, so I could log it.  I do not intend to serialize it in my application.

Comment: @Jørgen -- Yes, clearly that's so.  But how do I access the values in the unserialized array.

Comment: @Keith -- If I use 'application/json' as the content-type, I receive no data.

Comment: @Quentin, Thanks.  It does appear this is a duplicate -- I can now access the values with file_get_contents('php://input').

Comment: My underlying problem is now solved in the answer Quentin flagged, but I still wonder what the @ sign means in a serialized array.

Comment: The at (@) sign is for JSON-LD: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON-LD  -- Also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28999427/fasterxml-jackson-the-json-symbol

Comment: Actually, in this case, I don't think the @ sign represents use of JSON-LD.  I may re-post the question later on.