# Can not find a (Map) Key deserializer for type [simple type, class java.lang.Class<java.lang.Object>]

Tags: java, jackson

I used Jackson to serialize a `Map<Class<?>, BaseClass>`. There are multiple subclasses of `BaseClass`, and each one is properly annotated to be serialized/deserialized by Jackson.

1. Is it possible to invoke `ObjectMapper.readValue(file, Subclass.class)` and get a `Subclass` instance back?
2. If so, how do I avoid this exception?

```java
com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Can not find a (Map) Key deserializer for type [simple type, class java.lang.Class<java.lang.Object>]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.DeserializerCache._handleUnknownKeyDeserializer(DeserializerCache.java:578)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.DeserializerCache.findKeyDeserializer(DeserializerCache.java:168)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationContext.findKeyDeserializer(DeserializationContext.java:404)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.MapDeserializer.createContextual(MapDeserializer.java:231)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationContext.handleSecondaryContextualization(DeserializationContext.java:581)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationContext.findContextualValueDeserializer(DeserializationContext.java:369)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.StdDeserializer.findDeserializer(StdDeserializer.java:842)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializerBase.resolve(BeanDeserializerBase.java:514)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.DeserializerCache._createAndCache2(DeserializerCache.java:292)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.DeserializerCache._createAndCacheValueDeserializer(DeserializerCache.java:241)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.DeserializerCache.findValueDeserializer(DeserializerCache.java:142)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationContext.findRootValueDeserializer(DeserializationContext.java:381)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper._findRootDeserializer(ObjectMapper.java:3154)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper._readMapAndClose(ObjectMapper.java:3047)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.readValue(ObjectMapper.java:2100)
```

3. Shouldn't Jackson know how to deserialize `Class<?>` since it is a core JDK type?

**UPDATE**: I found https://stackoverflow.com/a/13954871/14731 which discusses how to implement Polymorphism in Jackson. That answers question #1 but leaves us with questions #2 and #3.

**UPDATE2**: Interesting. I found [ClassSerializer.java](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-databind/blob/master/src/main/java/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/ser/std/ClassSerializer.java) but there is no corresponding `ClassDeserializer.java` in https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-databind/tree/master/src/main/java/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/deser/std

**UPDATE3**: Filed a bug report: https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-databind/issues/630

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a known bug that should be fixed in version 2.5.0: https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-databind/issues/630