# Serlaize case class with the variable inside it in scala with jackson

Tags: java, json, scala, jackson, fasterxml

i am tiring to serialize a case class using jackson [fasterxml](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-module-scala), i can see the constructor parameters after deserialize (taskRequest and taskNameIn) but not the variables inside the class (jobsRequests is null for example):

```
//@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true) // tried to remove it with no luck
@JsonAutoDetect
case class Job(taskRequest: List[TaskRequest] = Nil,taskNameIn:String) {
{
this.jobsRequests = taskRequest
    this.taskName= taskNameIn
}
@JsonProperty
@volatile private var jobsRequests: List[TaskRequest] = Nil 

@JsonProperty
var task_name: String = ""

}
```

Any suggestions ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So there where some problems with the serialization, some where easy but i learn something that may help other people with this problem and the understanding of case class in general.

First, i used javap(.exe) to see the java code from the class files, to Job.scala with contained case class named Job, there are two class files: Job$.class and Job.class.

Job$.class:

```
public final class logic.Queue.Task.Job$ extends scala.runtime.AbstractFunction4<java.lang.Object, java.lang.String,   scala.collection.immutable.List<logic.Job.TaskRequest>, org.Server.Job.TaskContainer, logic.Queue.Task.Job>     implements scala.Serializable {
  public static final logic.Queue.Task.Job$ MODULE$;
  public static {};
  public final java.lang.String toString();
  .
  .
  .
}
```

Job.class:

```
public class logic.Queue.Task.Job implements scala.Product,scala.Serializable {
  public static org.Server.Job.TaskContainer apply$default$4();
  public static scala.collection.immutable.List<logic.Job.TaskRequest> apply$default$3();
  .
  .
  .
}
```

Meaning that the scala case class is an anonymous inner class and when you try to serialize it (and you can since both implements scala.Serializable), i solved it with adding to the signature to:

```
@JsonAutoDetect
@JsonTypeInfo(use = JsonTypeInfo.Id.CLASS, include = JsonTypeInfo.As.PROPERTY, property = "@class")
@JsonCreator
case class Job(stat: Int = CmsTypeMsg.Pending, jobName: String = "", taskRequestIn: List[TaskRequest] = Nil, taskIn: TaskContainer = new TaskContainer())
```

For more help on this issue:
http://www.jpalomaki.fi/?p=527
[Json deserialization into another class hierarchy using Jackson](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10329706/json-deserialization-into-another-class-hierarchy-using-jackson)

Answer (score 0):

Jackson uses Getter from the Java Beans standard to construct the json. Try adding `@BeanProperty` to your properties and constructor parameters to compile your class with Getter/Setters.

[Example](http://alvinalexander.com/scala/scala-javabeans-beanproperty-annotation)

Or you could use the Jackson [Scala-Module](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-module-scala). You can take a look at their tests to see how to use this module for [serialization](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-module-scala/blob/master/src/test/scala/com/fasterxml/jackson/module/scala/ser/CaseClassSerializerTest.scala).

Comment: Thanks for trying, in the end it was a wrapper case class that did the troubles.