# Deserializing parent and child node data of json in a single java object

Tags: java, json, gson

I am new to Java and I am facing problem converting json data to java object. Lets say my json format is

```
{
  "totalSize" : 2,
  "done" : true,     
  "Id" : "xyz",
  "Name" : "P0000005239",
    "child" : {      
      "Type" : "someType",
      "Region" : "someRegion",      
      "Name" : "C001906"      
    },
    "Address_1" : "Address_1",
    "Address_2" : "Address_1" 
  }
```

If my java class structure is like this, deserialization is working

```
//Working class Structure
class Demo{
   int total_Size;
   boolean flag_done;
   String ID;
   String p_name;
   Child child; 
   String Address1;
   String Address2;

   //getter and setter
  }
```

But my  class structure is(to which I am not able to map my json)

```
//Not Working
class Demo{
    int total_Size;
    boolean flag_done;
    String ID;
    String p_name;
    String c_type;
    String  c_region;
    String c_name;   
    String Address1;
    String Address2;

    //getter and setter
   }
```

**Error**

```
Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is 
com.google.gson.JsonParseException: The JsonDeserializer        
com.google.gson.DefaultTypeAdapters$CollectionTypeAdapter@4b28f983 failed to 
deserialized json object
```

How to create java object from json having all the data in single class(i.e parent and child node data in single class without declaring separate child class)

I am using GSON with @SerializedName annotation for converting json into java object. Please let me know if you need more detail.

Comment: have you created a Child class that contains your c_type, c_region, and c_name?

Comment: if I am creating child class then it is working, but I want all the property in one class(2nd class in the question).

Comment: looks like you would either have to create your own JSON parser or migrate the information for each Demo object you create into the c_ variables from their child classes.  [Check here](https://google-gson.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/gson/docs/javadocs/com/google/gson/Gson.html) for more info on the capability of GSON

Comment: Refer to this [one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10329706/json-deserialization-into-another-class-hierarchy-using-jackson) it's already answered here. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using fasterxml jackson

For this purpose you need to pass additional info in JSON:

```
@JsonTypeInfo(use=JsonTypeInfo.Id.NAME, 
  include=JsonTypeInfo.As.PROPERTY, property="@type")
class Base {
...
}
```

Then on serialization it will add @type field:

```
objectMapper.registerSubtypes(
        new NamedType(ConcreteAAdapter.class, "ConcreteA"),
        new NamedType(ConcreteBAdapter.class, "ConcreteB"),
        new NamedType(ConcreteCAdapter.class, "ConcreteC")
        );
```

// note, that for lists you need to pass TypeReference explicitly

```
objectMapper.writerWithType(new TypeReference<List<Base>>() {})
 .writeValueAsString(someList);




{
  "@type" : "ConcreteA",
  ...
  }
on deserialization it will be:



objectMapper.registerSubtypes(
        new NamedType(ConcreteA.class, "ConcreteA"),
        new NamedType(ConcreteB.class, "ConcreteB"),
        new NamedType(ConcreteC.class, "ConcreteC")
        );



objectMapper.readValue(....)
```

More here: http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonPolymorphicDeserialization