# Converting Json to Java Object containing variable of type (some subclass)

Tags: java, json, jackson

I'd like to map a JSON to POJO. The JSON format is:

```
{
    user: "123abc",
    messages: [
        {"type":"A", "args": {"a":"str", "b":0} },
        {"type":"B", "args": {"c":true, "d":false} },
        ...
    ]
}
```

Each type of message has its own expected args. For example:

```
class TypeAMessage extends Message {
    String a;
    int b;
}

class TypeBMessage extends Message {
    boolean c;
    boolean d;
}
```

I could map this JSON to a simple POJO like:

```
class Messages {
    @JsonProperty("user")
    String user;
    @JsonProperty("messageList")
    List<Message> messageList;

    class Message {
        @JsonProperty("type")
        String type;
        @JsonProperty("args")
        Map<String, Object> args;
    }
}
```

But this doesn't seem ideal, because `args` can contain multiple variable types (String, Integer, ...) and now they're all being stored as a general `Object` variable.

I already know what args to expect based on the message `type`. Since each `type` expects a different set of arguments, I thought of mapping the JSON to a class like this:

```
class Messages {
    @JsonProperty("user")
    String user;

    @JsonProperty("messageList")
    List<? extends Message> messageList;

    class Message {}

    class TypeAMessage extends Message {
        @JsonProperty("a")
        String a;
        @JsonProperty("b")
        int b;
    }

    class TypeBMessage extends Message {
        @JsonProperty("c")
        boolean c;
        @JsonProperty("d")
        boolean d;
    }
}
```

I'm using Jackson JSON, and JSON-to-object conversion fails with `Unrecognized field "a"` (and b, c, d too) because these fields are not in the parent `Message` class.

Am I going about this the wrong way? Or is there a way to contain each Message Child object, by telling the JSON Object Mapper to look for children to map to?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Json deserialization into another class hierarchy using Jackson](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10329706/json-deserialization-into-another-class-hierarchy-using-jackson)

Comment: @mlk Thanks for the link. I dug thru the link contents (and the link's links' contents) and found a solution. The solution is only a few lines on top of what's written in the question, and appears to be simpler than what is asked in your link. So I think it's helpful to keep this question open and answer it myself. If you don't disagree then I will follow through.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution is to add some annotations onto `Message` so that the JSON deserializer knows what subclass of `Message` to use:

```
class Messages {
    @JsonProperty("user")
    String user;

    @JsonProperty("messageList")
    List<Message> messageList;


    @JsonTypeInfo(use=JsonTypeInfo.Id.NAME, include=JsonTypeInfo.As.PROPERTY, 
            property="type")
    @JsonSubTypes( {
            @JsonSubTypes.Type(value=TypeAMessage.class, name="typeA"),
            @JsonSubTypes.Type(value=TypeBMessage.class, name="typeB")
    })

    static class Message {}

    static class TypeAMessage extends Message {
        @JsonProperty("a")
        String a;
        @JsonProperty("b")
        int b;
    }

    static class TypeBMessage extends Message {
        @JsonProperty("c")
        boolean c;
        @JsonProperty("d")
        boolean d;
    }
}
```

Example JSON message that specifies the subclass to use:

```
{
    "user":"someUser",
    "messageList":[
        {"type":"typeA", "a":"someStr", "b":123}, 
        {"type":"typeB", "c":false, "d":true}
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try make inner class static

```
static class TypeAMessage extends Message {
    @JsonProperty("a")
    String a;
    @JsonProperty("b")
    int b;
}

static class TypeBMessage extends Message {
    @JsonProperty("c")
    boolean c;
    @JsonProperty("d")
    boolean d;
}
```

Comment: Thanks though this does not solve the issue. Please refer to the answer I posted.