# Jackson polymorphism specified dynamically -- without @JsonSubTypes

Tags: jackson-databind

I have some polymorphic POJOS, and I know that I can leverage Jackson's polymorphism thusly:

```
@JsonTypeInfo(use=JsonTypeInfo.Id.NAME, property="message_type")
@JsonSubTypes({
    @JsonSubTypes.Type(name = "repo_item", value = Item.class),
    @JsonSubTypes.Type(name = "repo_folder", value = Folder.class)
})
public abstract class Node {
   UUID id;
   String name;
   @JsonProperty("message_type")
   public abstract String _getMessageType();
}
public class Item extends Node {
   String properties;
   @Override
   public String _getMessageType() { return "repo_node"; }
}
public class Folder extends Node {
   String color;
   @Override
   public String _getMessageType() { return "repo_folder"; }
}
```

This works great.  However, I don't know all of the subclasses of Node at compile time. I am generating code from an IDL definition, and the generated classes are subtypes of Node.  How can I register the equivalent of @JsonSubTypes annotation, but at run time?

Answer (score 0):

This seems to already be answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10329706/json-deserialization-into-another-class-hierarchy-using-jackson/13954871) and discussed further [here](https://octoperf.com/blog/2018/02/01/polymorphism-with-jackson/)

The short story is, if you cannot use @JsonSubTypes.Type annotation as indicated in my question, you register the class and its discriminator value on the object mapper when you create it:

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
mapper.registerSubtype("repo_folder", RepoFolder.class);
mapper.registerSubtype("repo_item", RepoItem.class);
```