# How to avoid class name in @type while serializing object to JSON using Jackson

Tags: java, json, jackson

I am using Jackson for serializing POJOs to JSON. But, I am getting the JSON as :

```
{
  "@type": "com.company.services.alert.dto.JungleEventDTO",
  "company": "xyz",
  "enabled": true,
  "support": false,
..
}
```

I do not want to expose my class name to the client.

How can I do this ?

Comment: Can you write your code where you are converting?

Comment: Not using any specific object mappers. Wanted to add some annotations over the JungleEventDTO , so that complete class name does not come in Json as part of abstraction

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use @JsonTypeId or @JsonTypeName or @JsonTypeInfo for Type handling.

Reference from https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-annotations/wiki/Jackson-Annotations

```
@JsonTypeId: property annotation used to indicate that the property value should be used as the Type Id for object, instead of using class name or external type name.
```

Also look at [How can I prevent Jackson from serializing a polymorphic type's annotation property?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5826928/how-can-i-prevent-jackson-from-serializing-a-polymorphic-types-annotation-prope)